# i want to handle database connection exception using spring security

Tags: spring, exception, servlets, spring-security

I am getting the following error:- **Login error. Reason : Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'dbname'** when i try to connect with wrong database. But i want to handle that exception and want to show some customize message.

Here is my configuration file:-
**Spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!--<http pattern="/abc/**" security="none" /> -->

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin*" access="hasRole('SYS_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cab-stop-admin*" access="hasAnyRole('SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/driver*" access="hasAnyRole('DRIVER','SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/customer*" access="hasAnyRole('CUSTOMER','SYS_ADMIN','CABSTOP_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/role-check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
            <remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/login" />

         </http> 

         <authentication-manager> 
        <authentication-provider> 
        <password-encoder hash="md5"  />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="fmsDataSource"  
        users-by-username-query="select Username,Password, 'true' as enabled from login_details where Username=?"
        authorities-by-username-query="select u.Username, ur.Role_Name from login_details u, role_master ur where u.Role_Master_Id = ur.Role_Master_Id and u.Username =? " />
    </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>

<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />

<html>
<head>
<title><spring:message code="message.home" /></title>
</head>

<body>
<c:if test="${not empty param.error}">
    <font color="red"><br /> Login error. 
    Reason : ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message} </font>

</c:if>
<form  name="loginForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<h1><spring:message code="message.login" /></h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><spring:message code="message.username"
            text="default text" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" autofocus="autofocus"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><spring:message code="message.password"
            text="default text" /></td>
        <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <label  for='_spring_security_remember_me'>
                        Remember me:
                        <input type='checkbox' name='_spring_security_remember_me' value="on"/>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit"
            value="<spring:message code="message.login" />" /></td>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/customer/register"><spring:message
            code="message.register" text="default text" /></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/forgot-password"><spring:message
            code="message.forgotpassword" text="default text" /></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
</html>
```

**hibernate-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cabfms.dao"/>

  <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="fmsDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${db.driverClassName}" p:url="${db.url}"
        p:username="${db.username}" p:password="${db.password}" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="fmsDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cabfms.entities" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">

            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            </props>
            <!--<props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">${hibernate.current_session_context_class}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">${hibernate.connection.pool_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">${hibernate.c3p0.timeout}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">${hibernate.c3p0.max_statements}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>


            </props>


        --></property>
    </bean>

      <!--Transaction Manager Added -->  
    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
</bean>


</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>

    <display-name>Web Application</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/hibernate-config.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/application-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>



    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <!--<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern> -->
        <!--<url-pattern>/views/*</url-pattern> -->
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping><!--

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

-->
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error-page</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>
```

Comment: add a try catch block where spring is trying to connect with DB and throw an custom exception with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your application container handle such exceptions.

Uncaught exceptions within an application can be forwarded to an error page as defined in the deployment descriptor (`web.xml`).

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

You just need to put exception type you want to handle and location where user will be forwarded in case of application error.

Remember to make this error page visible to anonymous users in case error happens before successful authentication.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/error" access="permitAll"/>
```

Comment: I have tried that buit t not working:--- <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error-page</location>
</error-page>
</web-app>

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want to receive help. Can you post all your xml files?

Comment: You don't appear to have added the `intercept-url` to your configuration as Maciej suggested. Also,if you want people to help please don't say "it's not working" without actually describing what happens in as much detail as you can.